# How do I prevent CloudFront & browser from caching files

Tags: amazon-s3, caching, amazon-cloudfront

I have a Vue.js app which is deployed on CloudFront + s3. I see that part of the clients receive an older version of the app, and I don׳t know how to decide if the issue is in the browser or in Cloudfront.

What have I done already?
Cloudfront - After every deployment I run invalidations.
Broswer - I tried to set 'Cache-Control' response header in S3 on index.html to 'no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate' and also to 'max-age=0'.

Unfortunately, Both of the solutions did not work.

Do you have a suggestion for more solutions that I can check?

Comment: have you found any solution to this? facing the same problem. interestingly, when I directly request cloudfront file by typing CF url in browser's address bar, it gets the file from cloudfront. however if CF url is accessed as cross-site, from `<script>`, the browser uses local disk cache